# How to resize an image with pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using python 3.6.9 and pillow 6.2.1 on a Mac Mojave I am trying to resize an image with pillow. Here is a complete example code:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image

data = numpy.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)
data[50, 51] = [255, 0, 0]
data[50, 52] = [0, 255, 0]
data[50, 53] = [0, 0, 255]

image = Image.fromarray(data)
image.save('orig.png')
image.resize((500,500))
image.save('resized.png')
```

I expect the image named `resized.png` to have 5 times the size as the image `orig.png`, but the images appear to have the same size, and they have the exact same file size.

Is that a bug in the `pillow` package or what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image.resize` returns the new image rather than changing the existing one

```
def resize(self, size, resample=NEAREST, box=None):
    # ...
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
```

You need to save the returned image

```
image = image.resize((500,500))
image.save('resized.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
image = image.resize((500,500))
```

the `resize` does not change the image size in-place, it returns the resized image.